# Unix permissions : allow users to create subdirectories only accessible by themselves

Tags: unix, permissions, chmod

This sounds simple, but I just can't find a good way to do this specifically - sorry if the answer was actually obvious.

I have a group, I have a directory, I want to make it so that users in this group can create subdirectories in that directory, and only the creator of a subdirectory has access to it.

How can I do this using unix permissions only (no ACL unfortunately) ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Wrong site. You're looking for [unix.se] instead. This site is for programming related questions, not general computer or OS support. You can find more information about this site in the [help].

Answer (score 0):

> Group: group1
> Users: usera, userb, userc

```
$ mkdir groupdir
$ chown usera:group1 groupdir
$ chmod 770 groupdir
$ /bin/ls -l
total 8
drwxrwx--- 2 usera group1 4096 Apr   1 21:09 groupdir
$
$ cd groupdir
$ mkdir dira
$ chown usera:usera dira
$ chmod 700 dira
$ /bin/ls -l
total 8
drwx------ 2 usera usera 4096 Apr    1 21:10 dira
```

Give permissions 770 (owner and group can do everything) to the top directory.  Then each sub-directory is created by a user in the group, and puts permissions 700 on it.  This way only the owner can user the sub-directory.